# Geometry Package Malfunction

Tags: geometry

[image: malfunction2][image: screenshot of geometry package malfunction]

Can anyone explain the demonstrated issue? I cannot get geometry to produce the proper size document for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys `height` and `width` set the text block dimensions, so giving those plus both margins over-specifies the layout and yields warnings

```
Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (397.48499pt) is ignored.


Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    `height' (668.4975pt) is ignored.
```

Presumably you wish to set the paper dimensions

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=9.25in,left=1.5in,right=.75in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

This is a not-correctly-sized document.

\end{document}
```